# I have wrong in my sql where is it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my sql query:

```
 SELECT pvl.name_parametre_value_parametre_value_lang,
       pv.id_parametre_value,
       ic.id_combinaison,
       ic.prix_combinaison,
       ic.poid_combinaison,
       ic.actif_combinaison,
       ic.actif_genere,
       pv.actif_value,
       pipv.id_parametre_value AS pipv_id_parametre_value
FROM   psimpserv_imp_combinaison_parametre_value_1 cpv
       LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_combinaison_1 ic
              ON ic.id_combinaison = cpv.id_combinaison
       LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_parametre_value pv
              ON pv.id_parametre_value = cpv.id_parametre_value
       LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_parametre_value_lang pvl
              ON pvl.id_parametre_value = pv.id_parametre_value
       LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_parametre p
              ON p.id_parametre = pv.id_parametre
       LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_product_impression_parametre_value pipv
              ON pipv.id_parametre_value = pv.id_parametre_value
                 AND pipv.id_product_impression = 6
WHERE  p.id_nom_domaine = 1
       AND pvl.id_lang_domaine = 3
       AND ic.id_product_impression = 6
       AND '250' LIKE (
Concat('%', pvl.name_parametre_value_parametre_value_lang, '_', pv.id_parametre, '%') )
-- AND '2' LIKE ( CONCAT('%',pvl.name_parametre_value_parametre_value_lang,'_',pv.id_parametre,'%') )
GROUP  BY ic.id_combinaison,
          cpv.id_parametre_value
ORDER  BY ic.id_combinaison,
          p.id_parametre
LIMIT  0, 32
```

MySQL returned an empty result.

Comment: show your database schema and correct the question formatting

Comment: i add like to searching in my DB but MySQL returned an empty result.

Comment: Several issues... 1. You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: 2. Move the WHERE clause conditions to the corresponding ON clause. (Use AND.) To get true LEFT JOIN result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT pvl.name_parametre_value_parametre_value_lang, pv.id_parametre_value, ic.id_combinaison, ic.prix_combinaison, ic.poid_combinaison, ic.actif_combinaison, ic.actif_genere, pv.actif_value, pipv.id_parametre_value AS pipv_id_parametre_value 
FROM
  psimpserv_imp_combinaison_parametre_value_1 cpv 
  LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_combinaison_1 ic 
    ON ic.id_combinaison = cpv.id_combinaison 
  LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_parametre_value pv 
    ON pv.id_parametre_value = cpv.id_parametre_value 
  LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_parametre_value_lang pvl 
    ON pvl.id_parametre_value = pv.id_parametre_value 
  LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_parametre p 
    ON p.id_parametre = pv.id_parametre 
  LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_product_impression_parametre_value pipv 
    ON pipv.id_parametre_value = pv.id_parametre_value 
    AND pipv.id_product_impression = 6 
WHERE p.id_nom_domaine = 1 
  AND pvl.id_lang_domaine = 3 
  AND ic.id_product_impression = 6 
  AND '250' LIKE (
    CONCAT(
      '%', pvl.name_parametre_value_parametre_value_lang, '_', pv.id_parametre, '%'
    )
  ) 
  AND '2' LIKE (
    CONCAT(
      '%', pvl.name_parametre_value_parametre_value_lang, '_', pv.id_parametre, '%'
    )
  ) 
GROUP BY ic.id_combinaison, cpv.id_parametre_value 
ORDER BY ic.id_combinaison, p.id_parametre 
LIMIT 0, 32
```

Comment: Please provide the clear error and not only the corrected query, as this helps the OP to spot his error

Comment: i add like to searching in my DB but 
MySQL returned an empty result.

Answer (score 0):

some things looks like error to me:

so here is the formatted query

```
SELECT
    pvl.name_parametre_value_parametre_value_lang,
    pv.id_parametre_value,
    ic.id_combinaison,
    ic.prix_combinaison,
    ic.poid_combinaison,
    ic.actif_combinaison,
    ic.actif_genere,
    pv.actif_value,
    pipv.id_parametre_value AS pipv_id_parametre_value
FROM
    psimpserv_imp_combinaison_parametre_value_1 cpv
LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_combinaison_1 ic ON
    ic.id_combinaison = cpv.id_combinaison
LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_parametre_value pv ON
    pv.id_parametre_value = cpv.id_parametre_value
LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_parametre_value_lang pvl ON
    pvl.id_parametre_value = pv.id_parametre_value
LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_parametre p ON
    p.id_parametre = pv.id_parametre
LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_product_impression_parametre_value pipv ON
    pipv.id_parametre_value = pv.id_parametre_value AND pipv.id_product_impression = 6
WHERE
    p.id_nom_domaine = 1 AND pvl.id_lang_domaine = 3 AND ic.id_product_impression = 6 AND '250' LIKE(
        CONCAT(
            '%',
            pvl.name_parametre_value_parametre_value_lang,
            '_',
            pv.id_parametre,
            '%'
        )
    )
    -- AND '2' LIKE ( CONCAT('%',pvl.name_parametre_value_parametre_value_lang,'_',pv.id_parametre,'%') )
GROUP BY
    ic.id_combinaison,
    cpv.id_parametre_value
ORDER BY
    ic.id_combinaison,
    p.id_parametre
LIMIT 0, 32
```

You need to check `--` in your query before AND

so this maybe the fixed one:

```
SELECT
    pvl.name_parametre_value_parametre_value_lang,
    pv.id_parametre_value,
    ic.id_combinaison,
    ic.prix_combinaison,
    ic.poid_combinaison,
    ic.actif_combinaison,
    ic.actif_genere,
    pv.actif_value,
    pipv.id_parametre_value AS pipv_id_parametre_value
FROM
    psimpserv_imp_combinaison_parametre_value_1 cpv
LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_combinaison_1 ic ON
    ic.id_combinaison = cpv.id_combinaison
LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_parametre_value pv ON
    pv.id_parametre_value = cpv.id_parametre_value
LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_parametre_value_lang pvl ON
    pvl.id_parametre_value = pv.id_parametre_value
LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_parametre p ON
    p.id_parametre = pv.id_parametre
LEFT JOIN psimpserv_imp_product_impression_parametre_value pipv ON
    pipv.id_parametre_value = pv.id_parametre_value AND pipv.id_product_impression = 6
WHERE
    p.id_nom_domaine = 1 AND pvl.id_lang_domaine = 3 AND ic.id_product_impression = 6 AND '250' LIKE(
        CONCAT(
            '%',
            pvl.name_parametre_value_parametre_value_lang,
            '_',
            pv.id_parametre,
            '%'
        )
    )
    AND '2' LIKE ( CONCAT('%',pvl.name_parametre_value_parametre_value_lang,'_',pv.id_parametre,'%') )
GROUP BY
    ic.id_combinaison,
    cpv.id_parametre_value
ORDER BY
    ic.id_combinaison,
    p.id_parametre
LIMIT 0, 32
```